# Does representation theory exists without Groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, semigroups, association-schemes

I need to know: is representation theory all about Groups?
Is it necessary to be a finite group?
Does representation theory exists without Groups?
For example is there sample where representation is about semi-group?

Comment: Instead of removing structure, you can add more - there is a huge amount of representation theory developed for rings and algebras (both associative and some non-associative).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a matrix representation theory of semigroups. For a survey, see [*Representations of semigroups by linear transformations*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02572292). 
 The term "representation theory" is much more general, not only for groups. Another well-known example is the representation theory of Lie algebras.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of an [association scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_scheme) is a generalization of the notion of a group. Many group-theoretic concepts — including representation theory — have natural generalizations to association schemes. The canonical reference is the book [*Theory of Association Schemes*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-26136-0) by Paul-Hermann Zieschang.

Answer (score 1):

For a more recent reference, see

J. Almeida, S. W. Margolis, B. Steinberg and M. V. Volkov, Representation theory of finite semigroups, semigroup radicals and formal language theory, *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **361** (2009), 1429-1461.

This paper contains an extensive bibliography on the representation theory of semigroups.